# Convert UTC date into date/time format in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am working with an API that only provides a UTC date/time as it's `publishedDate`. I want to convert that field into a specific date format, for example, `d-m-Y` or `H:i`. An example API field would be.

```
{
    "title": "This is a title"
    "thumbnail": "/path/to/image.jpg"
    "slug": "slug-of-story"
    "publishedDate": "2019-07-02T13:38:15.215Z"
}
```

Is there a way in vanilla javascript I can convert this value into a human readable date format that I specify?

I am using VueJS to render the API fields so I can attach a method to this specific field during the rendering phase. However, I am keen not use `momentJS` as I don't want to introduce a dependency for one JSON field.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to format a JavaScript date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date)

Answer (score 0):

```js
var a=new Date();
console.log(a.getDate() +"\\"+ Number(1+a.getMonth()) +"\\"+ +Number(1900+a.getYear()))
```